# JQuery button selector based on value

Tags: jquery

I have buttons with the same class but different values. I would like to select the correct button based on the value and hide it. This doesn't seem to work with JQuery 1.8.

```
 $(":button[value='1']").hide();
```

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/nbSUS/

Comment: It does work. You selector is right. http://jsfiddle.net/HNRF7/

Comment: Post your HTML please.

Comment: I think you don't load jquery check that it's loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine , check if jquery is included in your page ,if not  then  add this line in the head of your html page :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Also verify that your js code is inside `script` tag and is executed after DOM is loaded :

```
<script type='text/javascript' >

 $(document).ready( function(){

       //JS code should be here

  });    

</script>
```

Comment: Yes you all are correct. I feel stupid since I had 2 value statements in the html with different values.